# Start Filtered Values From One After Filter in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

After filtering values in excel, the row number of each filtered value remains as it was when the data was not filtered. 
Is there a way to ensure than whenever the values are filtered, the filtered values begin at 1 again?

Any help ill be appreciated.

Comment: Only by copying the filtered list to a new range.  Filtering just hides the rows visibly but they are still very much there on the same row numbers.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Is there a more advance filtering method that may be used to not only hide the other value, but to return only the filtered values?

Comment: Thanks pnuts, however, I am performing operations on these cells. As such, doing that doesn't make much of a difference.

Comment: Would you like a way to view the filtered data with sequential numbering??

Comment: @Gary's Student, right that is what I am looking for. Sequential numbering beginning from 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say we want to filter data like:

[image: first]

Put a header in cell **C1** and in **C2** enter:

```
=SUBTOTAL(3,$B$2:$B2)
```

and copy down.  We now apply the filter to column **B** and we see:

[image: after]

As you see, the *"Helper"* column give a nice sequential list of the visible cells.

- you can use **MATCH/INDEX** to retrieve any visible row's data.
- you can use **MAX** on column **C** to get a count of the visible rows, etc.